# What function space do $u(x)=\sin(x)$ and v$(x)=e^{-2x}$ belong to?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm trying to follow notes, a question is presented in the middle of the notes that isn't answered.

$u(x)=0$ when $-1\leq x<0$

$u(x)=x^2$ when $0\leq x \leq 1$

The $u(x)$ function belongs to $C^1[-1,1]$. What space do $u(x) = \sin x$ and $v(x) = e^{-2x}$ belong to?

Comment: This doesn't have a definite answer. For instance they belong to $C^1[-a,a]$ for any positive $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is what's the largest $n \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that $u \in C^n\lbrack-1,1\rbrack$ where $u(x) = \sin x$ or $u(x) = e^{-2x}$, then the answer (in both cases) is $n = \infty$. In fact we know that $u,v:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $u(x) = \sin x$ and $v(x) = e^{-2x}$ are both infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, which is a stronger assertion.